# Retrieve data from website database+how to

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have made a project and when people put a keyword into UITextfield and click the button then my app will retrieve the data from website database.

It is not working here is the code:

```
- (IBAction) btnClickMe_Clicked:(id)sender {        
    NSString *kw = s.text;  // <-----THIS IS THE UITextField        
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/index.php?keyword=",kw];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [iMessageLabel loadRequest:request];        
}
```

Any one could help me?

Comment: Do you really think that tagging your question with the words "retrieve" and "from" is going to help anyone?

Comment: My advice, don't send a messageLabel to do an NSURLConnection's job...!  No / that's not right. Anyway...
=> Read the NSURLConnection documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't putting the keyword into the string. You need something like this:

```
NSString *kw = s.text;
NSString *encodedkw =  [ky stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.example.com/index.php?keyword=%@", encodedkw];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Then look at how to use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) to figure out how to put the data into the label.